# Reflection to call a function in a class that satisfies a property

Tags: php, laravel, reflection

I have several classes that implement `IInfoProvider`.  Each subclass has a re-implemented function called `providesInfoFor()` which returns a `string` of the name of the type of device it can perform actions on.  Each subclass provides different types of actions.  For instance `ABCInfoProvider` will declare functions like `doThis($device)` and `doThat($device)` while `XYZInfoProvider` will declare functions like `doNow($device)` and `doLater($device)`.  I have not instantiated any instances of `ABCInfoProvider` or `XYZInfoProvider` so they do not appear in my list of `get_declared_classes`.  This is a Laravel based app and below is the snippet of code I'm trying to get working:

```
//Works if I uncomment these two lines, which I don't want to do
//$a = new ABCDeviceInfoProvider();
//$a = new XYZDeviceInfoProvider();

//Iterate over each class
foreach (get_declared_classes() as $className) {

    //Check if the class derives from IInfoProvider
    if (in_array(IInfoProvider::class, class_implements($className))) {

        //Create an instance of the class since it derives from IInfoProvider
        $infoProvider = new $className();

        //Check that the IInfoProvider has a specific function on it
        if (method_exists($infoProvider, $action)) {

            //Call the function, this is equivlent to 'new ABCInfoProvider()->doThis($device);'
            $response = $infoProvider->$action($device);

            return response()->json($response);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Action not implemented for device'], 400);
        }
    }
}
```

So, the question is, how can I get this to work if I haven't declared an instance of any of my `IInfoProviders` yet?  Is there another way altogether where I can at run-time call a function on a class that may or may not exist?